# Converting "normal date" in SAS original format

Tags: sas

Let's say I have a date like '21112021'. I want to convert this date as a number of days since the 1st January 1960.

How can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: What did you try?  Do you mean you have a character variable with that 8 digit string?

Answer (score 2):

Considering that you have a character variable - representing the 21th of November 2021, the following snippet should work:

```
data want;
d = "21112021";
date = input(d, ddmmyy10.);
format date date9.;
run;
```

For instance, the `INPUT()` function returns the value produced when a SAS expression is converted using a specified informat.

See more about [SAS Date, Time, and Datetime Values](https://go.documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lrcon/p1wj0wt2ebe2a0n1lv4lem9hdc0v.htm)